# Power Automate connectors are not visible

Tags: office-365, power-automate

I have created the service account and imported the flow to power automate and shared the flow with another user but somehow Connectors are not visible to the shared user and when another user logged in using the service account cannot see the connectors.

And the other user is logging from another region, How come any account logging to the flow cannot see the connectors.

Comment: Did you add another user as co-owner of flow and has same license as service account?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP Yes I did add as like service account with same license.